# Spring batch execute last step even get an exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I want to run a spring batch job which has set of steps and finally I want to send a notification to redis containing the status of the Job execution. Let's say if all the steps are executed, I should send "Pass". If there was any execution or any error, I want to pass "Fail". So my last step will be notification to redis updating the status regardless of it finished fine or got an exception.

My question is:

1. Can I achieve this in Spring Batch?
2. Can I use notification
   function as a last step or should I use any specific method for
   this?
3. How can I get the status of jobs?

I know I can get the job status like :

```
 JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, params);
 System.out.println("Exit Status : " + execution.getStatus());
```

But I call the job in command-line like `java -jar app.jar ----spring.batch.job.names=myjobnamehere` so that I do not use a JobExecution object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`JobExecutionListener`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/JobExecutionListener.html) for that. In the `afterJob` method, you have a reference to the `JobExecution` from which you can get the status of the job and send the notification as required.

You can find an example in the [getting started guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/) (See `JobCompletionNotificationListener`).

Comment: perfect! Thanks a lot!